# Is adding a column to database outside a migration class like controller safe against sql injection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have a code block like this in controller:

```php
if (!Schema::hasColumn($table_name, $key) && (count(Schema::getColumnListing($table_name)) < 250)) {
    Schema::table($document_metadata->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) use ($key) {
        $table->string($key)->nullable();
    });
}
```

Is it safe?